# Design-time-only background color in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, designer

In WPF XAML there is the convenient `DesignHeight` and `DesignWidth`, for instance in code as

```
<UserControl ... d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500" ... />
```

which is great because I can build the layout with a *representative*, but *not locked-in*, control size.

However, I'm often building dark UIs, where labels and so forth need to be white, but my controls still need a transparent background color. This creates a design-time inconvenience because white seems to be the default background color for transparent controls in the designer, leading to unreadable white-on-white labels.

Is there a way or strategy for setting the design-time background color, with similar convenience as DesignHeight/DesignWidth?

Comment: I'm not sure, by googling I found two documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839627(VS.100).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602277(v=vs.95).aspx). May be they will be helpfull

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183801/black-background-for-xaml-editor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAML : How to change background color only in Design mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843276/xaml-how-to-change-background-color-only-in-design-mode)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32874861/492 for the win

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer was found here: [Black Background for XAML Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183801/black-background-for-xaml-editor). There are a number of choices including checking `System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)` at runtime.

Answer (score 59):

There's an undocumented property `d:DesignStyle` of type `Style` that you can set on a user control. This style is only applied in the designer and is not used at runtime.

You use it like this:

```
<UserControl ... d:DesignStyle="{StaticResource MyDesignStyle}" />
```

Or like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="500" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500" />
        </Style>
    </d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
</UserControl>
```

The `Background` property is what you asked for. The `Height` and `Width` do replace your `d:DesignHeight=500` and `d:DesignWidth=500` in the `<UserControl>` tag. Then you have all your design properties at one place.

Note however, that any value set on the `Style` property (the one used at runtime) will also override the `DesignStyle` in the designer.

Comment: This is really nice and way easier than the other answers.

Comment: What is a design style and how to initialize it? To make this easy how do you set `d:DesignStyle` to White?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan In the second example code section above add `<Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />` into the `Style` node to set the Background color to white.

Comment: Trying the second method in .NET Core WPF. I get wiggly line below `Style` saying "Object reference not set to an instance of object", and the background does not change.

Answer (score 9):

I found that you can do one for yourself. [Custom design-time attributes in Silverlight and WPF designer](http://mnajder.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-design-time-attributes-in.html) is a tutorial how to do it for both Silverlight and WPF.

Comment: This one is a bit nicer to me then the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is much more modular and can be directly used in the designer without writing code for multiple controls.

Answer (score 3):

This is the complete solution for DesignBackground:

```
public class DesignTimeProperties : DependencyObject
    {
        private static readonly Type OwnerType = typeof(DesignTimeProperties);

        #region DesignBackground (attached property)

        public static Brush GetDesignBackground(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Brush)obj.GetValue(DesignBackgroundProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDesignBackground(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DesignBackgroundProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "DesignBackground",
                typeof (Brush),
                OwnerType,
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent,
                    DesignBackgroundChangedCallback));

        public static void DesignBackgroundChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsInDesignMode)
            {
                var control = d as Control;
                var brush = e.NewValue as Brush;
                if (control != null && brush != null)
                {
                    control.Background = brush;
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool IsInDesignMode
        {
            get
            {
                return
                    ((bool)
                        DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof (DependencyObject)).DefaultValue);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Usage:

```
<UserControl ... infra:DesignTimeProperties.DesignBackground="Black" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle` technique shown on this page works great for applying a **WPF** design-time-only style to a **single control**, but it doesn't appear to work for a `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` that would apply to *all* of the appropriately-typed controls or elements under the scope of the dictionary. Below is simple solution I found for deploying a designer-only style into a `ResourceDictionary`.

Consider for example a `Window` containing a `TreeView`, where we want the `TreeViewItem` nodes to show as fully expanded—but only at design time. First, put the desired style in the XAML dictionary in the normal way.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here, the `Style` is put in the `ResourceDictionary` of the `Window` but of course you could use any other subsuming dictionary instead. Next, in the C# code, *remove the style from the `Resource­Dict­ionary` when design mode is **not** detected*. Do this is in the `OnInitialized` override:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this) == false)
        Resources.Remove(typeof(TreeViewItem));

    base.OnInitialized(e);
}
```

**Design Mode:                                                        Runtime Mode:**

[image: design mode]    [image: runtime mode]