# Design-time-only controls, or where to find definition of the 'd' namespace?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a need to display a certain WPF control only in the [VS 2017] designer, but not during run time. (Specifically, a background image to lay out the components).

[As I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278611/3513925), the opposite effect (hiding a control at design time) can be achieved using the undocumented `d:IsHidden="true"` attribute, from the namespaces that are typically included even by default:

```
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

There is [another feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076419/design-time-only-background-color-in-wpf) to have a design-time style with `d:DesignStyle`.

But I couldn't find anything like `d:Visible` or something to the effect.

So, are there any *simple* methods to have a design-time-only component, similar to having a special 'd' attribute? I'd prefer not to use a custom code-behind, because there is at least a trivial (but annoying) solution: just comment out the component before compilation!

Ideally, the whole component should be disabled/removed at run time, so that it didn't take any resources.

More generally, is there a way to find all these 'undocumented' features of the `d` namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put this in your Window or UserControl constructor after the InitializeComponent() call:

```
if (!System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) 
{
    myDesignControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Doing this also allows the ability to turn the control back on again at runtime, which I often find useful for debugging tools or diagnostics.

Comment: That's what I'll have to do, in the end, until someone discovers a documentation for that Blend namespace, and there is something more useful in it...

Answer (score 1):

'd' is not magical nor anything official. It is an alias for an xml namespace that is local to to xaml/XML file where it is defined.

This line defines d in the code in the question:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

So to find information about 'features' of this namespace there should be a list of all classes that are in this namespace. Most of them are in the Microsoft Expression Blend SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22829

Comment: I have this SDK. But I couldn't find _any_ documentation on this namespace. By doing global search on the known keywords, I found that it belongs to `Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.SketchControls.design.v4.dll`, but no other trace anywhere else... It's a pity, because all the things I know (and mentioned) about it so far can be extremely useful.