# .NET Core WPF User Control set design-time background

Tags: wpf, .net-core, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2019

I tried the two methods explained in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866918/455796), but neither of them is working. How can I set the background colour?

**Method 1**

```
<UserControl x:Class="deletewpf.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:deletewpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignStyle="{StaticResource MyDesignStyle}"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="MyDesignStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>    
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

Method 2

```
<UserControl x:Class="deletewpf.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:deletewpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>
        <Style TargetType="UserControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </d:DesignerProperties.DesignStyle>    
    <Grid>
            
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

I had pressed Run to build it before getting those errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with the .NET Core designer. In .NET Framework both methods work, but for the first method, you would have to use a `DynamicResource`, because the style is declared after it is used.

```
d:DesignStyle="{DynamicResource MyDesignStyle}"
```

There is a workaround for .NET Core, that is also included in one of the answers. You have to declare a type that defines attached dependency properties that check if you are running design mode and sets the corresponding properties. This is an example for the `Background` property only, but it can be extend for using a `Style`, too.

```
public class DesignModeProperties : DependencyObject
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "BackgroundProperty", typeof(Brush), typeof(DesignModeProperties),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Transparent, OnBackgroundChanged));

   public static void OnBackgroundChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(d) && d is Control control && e.NewValue is Brush brush)
         control.Background = brush;
   }

   public static Brush GetBackground(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
   {
      return (Brush)dependencyObject.GetValue(BackgroundProperty);
   }

   public static void SetBackground(DependencyObject dependencyObject, Brush value)
   {
      dependencyObject.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Add the following line to your `UserControl` markup to enbale the design-mode background.

```
local:DesignModeProperties.Background="White"
```

Comment: The second method works, but how to get the first method working? How to define a "dynamic resource" MyDisignStyle? I have tried `Application.Current.Resources["MyDesignStyle"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);` as the existing answers for a dynamic resource example question, but that does not work.

Comment: Sorry, maybe that was a misunderstanding. Both methods that you have proposed currently **do not** work with .NET Core designer. I meant that even for your first method **in .NET Framework** you need to use the `DynamicResource` markup extension instead of `StaticResource`, because otherwise there would be an error. By the way, using the dynamic markup extension only changes the way that the resource is _resolved_. You do not have to define resources differently for that.

Comment: So, using `DesignModeProperties ` class is currently the only working way for .NET Core WPF? Anyway, I knew that .NET Core WinForms designer is currently problematic, but I did not know .NET Core WPF designer is so, too. And the new MAUI is not coming until next year...

Comment: At least with the current version of Visual Studio 2019 none of the other XAML based approaches are working in the designer.